# Suddently I can't access shared drive - DNS?

Tags: windows, dns, nas, file-server

I have a Synology NAS.

In my DSN server, I have two entries pointing to the same IP of my Synology NAS (10.0.1.1)...

> MySynologyNas
>
> MyFileServer

Suddently during the day, I can't accesss "MySynologyNas", while I have no problem accessing the NAS from "MyFileSever" and from IP 10.0.1.1.

If I reboot my Windows 10 Pc, I can access "MySynolgyNas" again.

I have no clue where to start looking, so any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A few things to test with when it happens and maybe try these while it is working and see the output and save to a file to review and compare when it is a problem.... `NSLOOKUP MySynologyNas`, `TRACERT MySynologyNas` and then try `IPCONFIG /FLUSHDNS` and then try those both again when there are problems. Maybe check event viewer and see if there are any relevant errors in there from the system logs. Quick ideas but ensure the DNS records have propagated to all DNS servers/DCs in your domain so if you have redundant internal DNS IP settings in `IPCONFIG /ALL` check all the DNS server records.

Comment: Also, please clarify how you are trying to access these when you have the problem e.g. via mapped drives, UNC paths, or some other method such as through an application or what? Checking the file/NAS server logs may be helpful as well potentially so there are some starting points perhaps to help troubleshoot.